# pick and transfer a column in excel without VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following problem. I have three columns in Excel, each with its own title/header. I want to pick and transfer one of the columns based on its title/header, without using VBA. Let me give an example. My data set is the following:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
1
2              C1   C2    C3
3              1    4     7 
4              2    5     8
5              3    6     9
6
```

I want to put the title/header of the column at eg B2 and get the data of the column, as shown below:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
1
2     C1       C1   C2    C3
3     1        1    4     7 
4     2        2    5     8
5     3        3    6     9
6
```

And when I change to eg C3, I get the C3 column:

```
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I
1
2     C3       C1   C2    C3
3     7        1    4     7 
4     8        2    5     8
5     9        3    6     9
6
```

My understanding is that I need to put a formula in B2, I just don't know how to structure it. It seems like a vlookup, but vlookup finds and picks at the same direction, while I want to find my variable searching horizontally and then pick vertically.

I know how to do it using VBA, but I would like to do it without using it. I would also welcome an elegant VBA code, but avoiding VBA would be better. I am new in Excel/VBA, so any help is welcome. Thanks in advance!

Comment: what am i looking at? A B C D E F G H I 1 2 C1 C2 C3 3 1 4 7 4 2 5 8 5 3 6 9 6?  are these columns? I don't think it's formatted properly.

Comment: You may want to see [How To Ask Good Questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: It's not at all clear what your data looks like, but you basically want INDEX and MATCH formulas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Updated to match the cells in your example.

Use this formula on your column B3 and drag the handle down to copy to other cells below.

```
=OFFSET(E3,0,MATCH($B$2,$E$2:$G$2,0)-1)
```

you should end up with the following formula in cell B3, B4, B5

```
=OFFSET(E3,0,MATCH($B$2,$E$2:$G$2,0)-1)
=OFFSET(E4,0,MATCH($B$2,$E$2:$G$2,0)-1)
=OFFSET(E5,0,MATCH($B$2,$E$2:$G$2,0)-1)
```

Now when you change the value in B2, say to "C3". the columns below will change to "C3" data accordingly.

let me know if you ran into any problems. kindly accept if this answered your problem.

Comment: Thanks Keith for the answer and the promptness. I have also found an alternative formula, but it requires to put an additional column of 1,2,3... next to the column I want the results: =HLOOKUP($B$2,$E$2:$G$5,A3+1). It works but it is not as elegant as yours. Thanks.